# Move icons on IPhone desktop to another screen

Tags: macos

How to move icons from one screen to another  on desktop IPhone. Tried holding finger on icon and swiping toward other screen with available space.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try http://apple.stackexchange.com/ (and delete this question) or flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 1):

Tap and hold icon until icons start to wiggle. Drag and hold icon at right or left edge of screen to move to next screen. Press home button when done.

It may help to tap and hold the edge of the icon opposite the direction you'd like to move it so that it starts to disappear when dragged over the edge.